# Eigen 'undefined reference to' error when -O2 is set

Tags: c++, linker, undefined-reference, eigen

I'm having some trouble getting Eigen to compile with optimisations -O2 set. If I swap the -O2 for -g compilation completes, and the program runs without error. With -O2 set, the linker throws out the below:

```
build/main.o:main.cpp:function displayTrainingScoreInfo(): error: undefined reference to 'TrainingManager::sumAllScores(std::vector<Eigen::Array<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, std::allocator<Eigen::Array<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> > >&)'
```

I do get a warning earlier in the compilation whichever options I compile with

```
warning: inline function ‘double TrainingManager::sumAllScores(std::vector<Eigen::Array<double, -1, 1> >&)’ used but never defined
```

I suspected that this was caused because I initialise the Eigen arrays to a certain size. This is NOT a size known at compile time (see below). But I've tested them uninitialised and I get the same issue

TrainingManager.h contains the definition:

```
inline double sumAllScores(std::vector<Eigen::ArrayXd > & scaledScores);
```

main.cpp - The offending function minus some user output (Errors intact)

```
void displayTrainingScoreInfo() {
    if (nnLoaded) {
        // Get all the calculation data
        const int nCases = tm.cases->nCases;
        const unsigned nOutputs =  tm.cases->nOutputs;
        std::vector<Eigen::ArrayXd > results(nCases,Eigen::ArrayXd(nOutputs));
        std::vector<Eigen::ArrayXd > scores(nCases,Eigen::ArrayXd(nOutputs));
        std::vector<Eigen::ArrayXd > scaledScores(nCases,Eigen::ArrayXd(nOutputs));
        tm.calculateAllCases(nn.mlp,results);
        tm.score(results,scores);
        tm.scale(scores,scaledScores);

        // SOME USER OUTPUT LOOPS OMITTED

        std::cout << "\nMLP TestCase Total:\t" << tm.sumAllScores(scaledScores) << std::endl;

    } else {
        error_msg("You must load cases and a network before you can see scores");
    }
}
```

TrainingManager.cpp

```
double TrainingManager::sumAllScores(std::vector<Eigen::ArrayXd > & scaledScores) {
    double total = 0.0;
    unsigned outputs = scaledScores.at(0).size();
    for (unsigned x = 0; x < scaledScores.size(); x++) {
        for (unsigned y = 0; y < outputs; y++) {
            total += scaledScores.at(x)[y];
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

What's the best way for me to avoid these errors? Or, what am I doing wrong with Eigen!?

If you want information on something please ask.

Comment: where is sumAllScores code is defined? not only prototype, but code?

Comment: Its in TrainingManager.cpp - It works fine, but I'll add it

Comment: You should always place inline function definitions in header files along with the declarations.

Comment: move all definitions of sumAllScores to single file, preferable .h file

Comment: I thought the 'inline' keyword was only used in the header, but the definition could go into the .cpp? Is this a bad practice?

Comment: It is. The official recommendation is to put inline functions in the header file to make sure the compiler can see it in every translation unit where you include them.

Comment: Ok, that seems to have done it :)